# Do I need a local copy of react-native for each project?

Tags: react-native

I'm just getting into [react-native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content) (for Android) and one thing that bothers me is that it seems to be enforcing a model where the SDK is duplicated for each project. `react-native init AwesomeProject` installs `react-native` under `node_modules` in the local folder. Although hard disk space is cheap, I'm bothered with the fact that the SDK of ~85MB & ~17k files is duplicated for each project I create. Couldn't/shouldn't this be installed and used globally?

I tried installing it globally with `npm install -g react-native`. While that works and I'm able to execute the `react-native` command, it fails when adding the parameter `run-android`:

```
Command `run-android` unrecognized. Did you mean to run this inside a react-native project?
```

Starting the packager from the global folder however, works. So I'm actually able to have a working dev environment without react-native installed locally as long as I do the building from Android Studio. So my question is two fold-

1. How can I get `run-android` to work as well when having react-native installed globally?
2. Why has Facebook built it so that the `react-native init` function installs the framework locally and not globally?

PS: I'm actually running this on Windows 10. Not sure if that is relevant (I've got it all working while installing it locally, as I said)

Comment: Did hit this problem as well after I've deleted my node-modules and ran $ npm i. I did solve this by installing locally (as you've said) the react-native-cli again. Weird occurrence indeed.